# Dual boot Mac/Win crashes in Windows

Tags: bootcamp, imac, windows

I have plenty of experience with dual boot, but never anything like this. State of the art iMac Retina 4K, 21.5-inch, Late 2015, running El Capitan 10.11.3, dual booting to very recent Windows 10. (Don't want to boot it to determine exact release.) So far no crashes on Apple side. On Windows side, twice now: screen goes black, pause, buzzing sound, then many rounds of Windows saying it will fix itself, then crashes again. In these many times it says it will fix itself there has been no buzzing. Today it ran Windows for 20 minutes or so, and then I again got the buzzing. For now, I'm just going to leave it in Apple and see if that crashes, which would suggest hardware.

Comment: Are you running the latest release of Windows 10?

Comment: Put it this way: I have accepted all upgrades they have offered me.

Comment: I risked booting in Windows to check the version. The Product ID is
00326-10001-27412-AA108, but that doesn't match anything on a search.

Comment: This just in...it's worked in Windows for an hour this morning. Fingers crossed.

Comment: Actually worked for two hours. Then when I had to run InDesign, I moved to my old computer because I didn't want to risk a crash with a big document. It crashed while it was sitting untouched on my desk.

Comment: Was this a fresh Windows install, or was it an update from Win 8/7? Also, are you having any problems with the machine while in OS X?

Comment: Fresh install on brand new computer. So far no problems with OS X.

Comment: It definitely is a software problem, not hardware.

Comment: I'm guessing it's a video driver problem. Just now, in the brief period before Windows crashed, it said I needed one, but then it just crashed...

Answer (score 2):

Late model macs such as yours have good support for EFI boot for windows and OS/X. I assume you have installed both via EFI on a disk partitioned using GPT partition scheme.

I am very familiar with the windows 8.1/10 cycle of trying to fix itself, it never will fix itself, this is something you need to help it with.

I spent more than a couple of days last week playing with EFI dual boot for Windows and Mac but my Mac isn't up to it. It's an early model 2011 MBP.

I had fun but **no sound** in windows. I could not fix the sound issues, not the constant (in Windows):

- crash, trying to repair
- restart, trying to repair
- crash, trying to repair

Your issue is almost certainly related to the way in which you prepared your machine. including the windows drivers you installed.

Have a look at this post from Jamie Osborne. I know Jamie and have worked with him. His guide is for 8.1 but should equally be suitable for 10.

http://jmeosbn.github.io/blog/windows-8.1-efi-install/

What might be more suitable for your situation is the following link. This is real bare bones stuff and requires knowledge. Not for the faint hearted:

https://www.reddit.com/r/mac/comments/2fy3be/by_popular_demand_my_better_than_bootcamp_guide/

have fun!

In my case, and for the sake of my sanity, I reverted to BIOS boot for windows. That's ok in my case as I also have Ubuntu and GRUB on there as well. The extra button click on startup is tolerable for me.

Comment: I don't believe I did much of anything other than exactly what the Bootcamp installation instructions told me to. I had to do it over and over because the extremely high pixel density of the monitor made the disk formatting dialogs very hard to perceive. It worked fine for 3 weeks of active use, then I was out of town for two and it sat off. The only hard drive currently on the machine is solid state, with a small OS-X partition and a 286GB Windows one.

Answer (score 1):

A week of frustration later, I'm going to give up and give the Mac to my wife, who only wants to use Apple. I'll get a PC for myself.

Did repeated complete reinstalls of everything. (Never got around to actual user software.) There was always *some* problem, just never the same. Just now downloaded current OS-X El Capitan software, did current updates, plus today's version of Windows 10. Everything ran smoothly until it tried to boot, and then it started repairing itself over and over. At least the last time, yesterday, it had booted a bit before it went black and started making the same noise it made in my first-described experience. My hunch is that it has to do with the video drivers, but rebooting with the "low resolution option" didn't work either.